# Add help button to Extjs gridpanel header

Tags: javascript, extjs, gridpanel

I want to add a button to the right hand side of my gridpanel header but can't find anyway of doing so.

I don't want to add a toolbar since it's only 1 button I want to add.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out the panel's [tools](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-tools) config. Simply add it to grid's config:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    // ...
    tools:[
    {
        type:'help',
        tooltip: 'Get Help',
        handler: function(event, toolEl, panel){
            // show help here
        }
    }],
    // ...
});
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/nwMDj/).

Comment: Can similar behavior be achieved with ExtJS 3.4.0?

Comment: @Jay, yes. See the docs http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-cfg-tools

Comment: @MolecularMan of course. Actually I did notice that, but when I was playing around with the jsfiddle of yours, help tool didnt show up and that gave me an impression that its not working with 3.4.0. Digging a bit more, found that 3.4.0 has qtip instead of tooltip and also jsfiddle has some issues with 3.4.0, those tool icons don't showup. If I run the same script in my chrome/firefox as a stand alone html/js file, it works. Anyway thanks for your reply and also for original solution.